# Show or Hide Jsf Richfaces modal panel from java bean

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, panel, ajax4jsf

In `JSF Richfaces`, I need to show or hide `modalpanel` and `GIF` image from bean according to certain functions.

For example, after I have entered all values and click submit means, processing `GIF` image will be displayed. At the time of completion it gets hidden by using

```
  onclick="#{rich:component('wait1')}.show()",
  oncomplete="#{rich:component('wait1')}.hide()"
```

`wait1` is an image file name I have used.

At the time of submitting, I have been validating the required fields.

If its empty, I want to hide the process image and show the `modalpanel` to get value from user.

How to hide the processing image and display the modal panel to get input from user, from `java` back bean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you a solution. Create Modal panel with property "showWhenRendered" .
create modalpanel as

```
 <rich:modalPanel id = "idd" autosized="true" width="500" height="50"
  showWhenRendered = "#{bean.booloeanvalue}">
  </rich:modalPanel>
```

In Bean, create boolean variable booloeanvalue. If booloeanvalue is true, automatically modalpanel is rendered and came to display.